# Clone Azure VM that was attached to a domain

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, rdp

Im going to start from the very beginning in hope that it helps people understand the issue better...

I started with an Azure VM running Windows Server 2016 (Lets call this VM: VM1) which was not connected to a domain controller - At this point I could RDP into VM1

I copied the OS disk and data disk VHD's of VM1 to another resource and created a new VM (VM2) from these VHD's - At this point I could RDP into VM2

I attached VM1 to the domain controller hosted on another machine, rebooted VM1 and could still RDP into VM1

I shut down VM1, and copied the OS disk and data disk VHD's to another resource and created a new VM (VM3) from these VHD's - However I am unable to RDP into VM3.

I have tried the various generic troubleshooting tips from Azure when having problems establishing an RDP connection and have not had any luck.

Can anyone solve this problem?

Comment: You have mentioned, "I attached VM1 to the domain controller hosted on another machine”, Is that an Azure VM? are they are in the same network/region? 
What specific error message do you receive when attempting to RDP?

Review the VM console logs and screenshot to determine if the VM is reporting an issue. You may consider posting a screenshot here.

Comment: Domain controller is hosted on another Azure VM. When trying to connect by RDP to VM3, it does not progress from 'Configuring connect' (I think thats what it says, I will confirm when I finish reproducing this issue in half hour or so). VM console logs look fine and boot diagnostic screen shows logon screen as expected.

Comment: I'm assuming you've checked endpoints,  security groups,  etc?

Comment: I would try detaching, reattaching the network card. Then RDP to one of your other VMs (VM1 or the DC) and try to remote into VM3. Maybe even use PowerShell and try to connect to the VM.

Comment: endpoints, security groups etc have been checked. Also tried detaching and reattaching the network card. tried RDPing from another VM to this one too. The problem seems to be around the fact that this machine is attached to a domain that it can no longer contact and around the fact that it has moved from one resource group to another

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0):

> However I am unable to RDP into VM3

Can you telnet that VM with port 3389?

I test it with your steps, I can't reproduce your error.

Could you show the error message when you try to RDP this VM?

For test, could you please use this [template](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/master/201-vm-specialized-vhd) to create a new VM with that VHD, and try to RDP it again.

Comment: When you tried it with my steps, the new VM in a separate resource group, I assume on your setup it was unable to contact the domain because its on its own network?

Comment: I havn't user Telnet much in the past, if I do 'telnet {IP} 3389', i believe it is connecting, the cmd window clears and then I just get a blinking courser. I will try using your template to create the VM.

Comment: Telnet Update, I have just tried telnet with the VM turned off and get the same, a blinking courser, so not im thinking it wasnt connecting before when the VM was turned on

Comment: So I have just created the VM again but using the template you provided, and I have the same result, that RDP is unable to connect. When trying to connect to RDP, it reaches 'Configuring remote session...'  but never progresses

Comment: @Jeffrey which type of your account? can you use that VM's account to RDP it, don't use AD user.

Comment: @Jeffrey Does that issue resolved? please let me know if you need more help:)

Comment: When attempting to RDP into the machine, it doesn't reach the stage of asking for a username and password, so cannot enter an AD user or the VM's administrator user. Issue is unfortunately still present.

Comment: The issue was a GPO being applied on the machine when it connected to the domain which set some bad firewall rules

Answer (score 0):

The issue was a GPO being applied on the machine when it connected to the domain which set some bad firewall rules